# can I have aria-hidden behave differently for on tab and hover events in chrome

Tags: html, accessibility

I have below html structure, and we dont want the screen reader to read the "click me" text on tab, but on hover the screen reader is supposed to read.

```
    <button aria-label="blank" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" >click me</button>
```

In Firefox and IE, screen reader is behaving as we expect, I mean on tabbing, screen reader is saying blank, and on hover it is saying click me.
However in chrome, screen reader is saying blank for both the events.
May I know how we can make screen reader behave in the same way in chrome as well.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: I don't understand you. do you want to show the label  onhover event?

Comment: @VivekSolanki on hover , screen reader must read "click me"  but not blank, only on tabbing screen should read "blank" , this is happening in firefox and ie, but i need this in chrome as well :)

Comment: check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6xbkdy53/2/ is this what you want?

Comment: thanks for your help Vivek, I dont want to use css for this, the html that I have provided works good in firefox and ie, only in chrome screen reader is not able to read the button text on hover

Comment: If a screen reader user is totally blind, how do they hover if they can't see the screen?  Also, you are breaking rule #2, https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second-rule-of-aria-use.  You are changing the semantic rules of a <button> by giving it a role of "presentation".